# Dynamically updating column value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am passing one password value for either 2 or 3 or 4 or 'n' number of usernames.

How to pass the user_id dynamically to the update query ?

```
update user_table
set column_password = 'password value'
where user_id in ( )
```

Comment: Is this in a stored procedure, or something else?

Comment: its in the stored procedure

Comment: And how is this value coming across in the parameter to the stored procedure?  What's an example value of @param ?

Comment: Have not decided, should be xml.

Comment: @param will have a xml format of value passed from c#.net application

Comment: c#.net values are stored inside a hashtable - datacollection

Comment: You should display how the parameter value looks like. Just saying it will be XML means almost nothing.

Comment: i got the answer from Dmitri. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create the function using this code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitIDs]
(
    @List varchar(5000)
)
RETURNS 
@ParsedList table
(
    ID int
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID varchar(10), @Pos int

    SET @List = LTRIM(RTRIM(@List))+ ','
    SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @List, 1)

    IF REPLACE(@List, ',', '') <> ''
    BEGIN
        WHILE @Pos > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @ID = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@List, @Pos - 1)))
            IF @ID <> ''
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @ParsedList (ID) 
                VALUES (CAST(@ID AS int)) --Use Appropriate conversion
            END
            SET @List = RIGHT(@List, LEN(@List) - @Pos)
            SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @List, 1)

        END
    END 
    RETURN
END

GO
```

then in your stored procedure declate `@UserIDs varchar(max)`. You will pass comma separated ID list into this param.

Then in your Stored proc you can have:

```
update U
set U.column_password = 'password value'
FROM dbo.SplitIDs(@UserIDs) I
INNER JOIN user_table U ON I.ID=U.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks. My understanding about the function is that , input parameter @List accepts only comma separated value.

Comment: Yeah, just like i said in my answer: "You will pass comma separated ID list into this param."

Answer (score 1):

**CREATE A Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FnSplit]
(
@List nvarchar(2000),
@SplitOn nvarchar(5)
)
RETURNS @RtnValue table (Id int identity(1,1), Value nvarchar(100))
AS
BEGIN

While(Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)>0)

  Begin


        Insert Into @RtnValue (value)

        Select Value = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@List,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)-1)))

        Set @List = Substring(@List,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)+len(@SplitOn),len(@List))

  End


Insert Into @RtnValue (Value)

Select Value = ltrim(rtrim(@List))

Return

END
```

**Store Procedure**

```
CREATE Procedure usp_Multipleparameter (@Users VARCHAR(1000)= NULL)
AS
BEGIN

        update user_table
        set column_password = 'password value'
        where user_id collate database_default IN (SELECT Value FROM dbo.FnSplit(@Users,','))

END
GO
```

**Calling Store Procedure**

```
EXEC usp_Multipleparameter 'User1,User2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought.  If this is already in a stored procedure it is likely you already have the user_id available to you through a select statement.  I would do something like this.

```
update user_table
set column_password = 'password value'
where user_id in ( select user_id from table
where criteria = '' )
```

Comment: in the subquery you are mentioning the user_id. in my scenario, user_id is passed dynamically. number of user_id's will change

Comment: Hi goofyui,  the statement would handle any number of user_ids whether it was one to one million or any number for that matter based on what the sub query picks up.  I believe from what I see from you above comments though that you may be looking for something else.